# How to sort/order based on custom field value within posts

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, sorting

Okay so let me try to explain this. This is a wordpress based question. I'm using the plugin "Advanced Custom Fields" documentation here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/

I created a numeric field for my posts. So basically every post I create has a numeric value associated with it.

Here is the info of my custom field:
Field Label: Sale Price
Field Name: sale_price
Field Type: number

What I want is to be able to order these posts in ascending and descending order (not at the same time of course).

What would be the easiest way of doing this?
Also, I think this may affect answers, I'm using this plugin as a filter http://codecanyon.net/item/taxonomies-filter-widget/4282257?WT.ac=solid_search_item&WT.seg_1=solid_search_item&WT.z_author=waylay (but it doesn't offer ascending or descending options)

I'm thinking some Jquery would be best so that I can possible avoid conflicts with the plugin. The plugin displays different posts based on the criteria of the filter(s), so I'm thinking a jquery function that orders whatever is displaying on that current page, would be the easiest way to go???

But I'm just not sure how to go about this.

I'll take all the help I can get on this one!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly,using this WP query will help you

```
        $args = array(
          'type' => 'numeric',
          'meta_key' => 'Sale Price',
          'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
           'order' => 'ASC')
```

Comment: thanks for this. But how do I make it so that the posts are not ordered by default, but only when a button is pressed. This is also why i'm leaning towards JS, but not sure if it has the functionality to do such a thing. Any thoughts?

Comment: use ajax then ,when you press a button an ajax function will be initiated ,you can get this result from another php page and use it in the current page